# Match the behavior of prefix_sep argument to pandas.get_dummies, in polars

Tags: python-polars

**Note**: I think this is no longer relevant, polars has had the separator argument in to_dummies for a long time now.

---

I have a variable `driver_age` and some levels `16_to_25`, `25_to_34`, etc.
I would like the dummy encoded columns to have names like `driver_age@16_to_25`.

I have the following workaround, but it is incompatible with LazyFrames.

```
prefix_sep = "@"
for col in features_categorical:
    ddf = df.get_column(col).to_dummies()
    new_names = [f"{col}{prefix_sep}{x[len(col)+1:]}" for x in ddf.columns]
    mapper = dict(zip(ddf.columns, new_names))
    ddf = ddf.rename(mapper)
    df = df.drop(col).hstack(ddf)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Would it be reasonable to request this as a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (somewhat) easier way to accomplish this is to add the `@` as a suffix to your `Categorical` columns, and then target the `@_` with a simple list comprehension.

Let's start with this data.

```py
import polars as pl
df = (
    pl.DataFrame([
        pl.Series(
            name='driver_age',
            values=['16_to_25', '25_to_34', '35_to_45', '45_to_55'],
            dtype=pl.Categorical),
        pl.Series(
            name='marital_status',
            values=['S', 'M'] * 2,
            dtype=pl.Categorical
        ),
        pl.Series(
            name='col1',
            values=[1, 2, 3, 4],
        ),
        pl.Series(
            name='col2',
            values=[10, 20, 30, 40],
        ),
    ])
)
df
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌────────────┬────────────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ driver_age ┆ marital_status ┆ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---        ┆ ---            ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ cat        ┆ cat            ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞════════════╪════════════════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 16_to_25   ┆ S              ┆ 1    ┆ 10   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 25_to_34   ┆ M              ┆ 2    ┆ 20   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 35_to_45   ┆ S              ┆ 3    ┆ 30   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 45_to_55   ┆ M              ┆ 4    ┆ 40   │
└────────────┴────────────────┴──────┴──────┘
```

We use the [`suffix`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.suffix.html) Expression to add a `@` to the end of the column names that are Categorical and create our dummy variables.

```py
df = (
    pl.get_dummies(
        df
        .select([
            pl.exclude(pl.Categorical),
            pl.col(pl.Categorical).suffix('@'),
        ]),
        columns=[s.name + '@' for s in df.select(pl.col(pl.Categorical))]
    )
)
df
```

```
shape: (4, 8)
┌──────┬──────┬──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ driver_age@_16_to_25 ┆ driver_age@_25_to_34 ┆ driver_age@_35_to_45 ┆ driver_age@_45_to_55 ┆ marital_status@_M ┆ marital_status@_S │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                  ┆ ---               ┆ ---               │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ u8                   ┆ u8                   ┆ u8                   ┆ u8                   ┆ u8                ┆ u8                │
╞══════╪══════╪══════════════════════╪══════════════════════╪══════════════════════╪══════════════════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 10   ┆ 1                    ┆ 0                    ┆ 0                    ┆ 0                    ┆ 0                 ┆ 1                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 20   ┆ 0                    ┆ 1                    ┆ 0                    ┆ 0                    ┆ 1                 ┆ 0                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ 30   ┆ 0                    ┆ 0                    ┆ 1                    ┆ 0                    ┆ 0                 ┆ 1                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4    ┆ 40   ┆ 0                    ┆ 0                    ┆ 0                    ┆ 1                    ┆ 1                 ┆ 0                 │
└──────┴──────┴──────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

From here, it's a one-liner to change the column names:

```py
df.columns = [col_nm.replace('@_', '@') for col_nm in df.columns]
df
```

```
shape: (4, 8)
┌──────┬──────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ driver_age@16_to_25 ┆ driver_age@25_to_34 ┆ driver_age@35_to_45 ┆ driver_age@45_to_55 ┆ marital_status@M ┆ marital_status@S │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---              ┆ ---              │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ u8                  ┆ u8                  ┆ u8                  ┆ u8                  ┆ u8               ┆ u8               │
╞══════╪══════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 10   ┆ 1                   ┆ 0                   ┆ 0                   ┆ 0                   ┆ 0                ┆ 1                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 20   ┆ 0                   ┆ 1                   ┆ 0                   ┆ 0                   ┆ 1                ┆ 0                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ 30   ┆ 0                   ┆ 0                   ┆ 1                   ┆ 0                   ┆ 0                ┆ 1                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4    ┆ 40   ┆ 0                   ┆ 0                   ┆ 0                   ┆ 1                   ┆ 1                ┆ 0                │
└──────┴──────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

It's not done in Lazy mode, but then again, the `get_dummies` is also not available in Lazy mode.